# Solving an equation modulo 9

Tags: number-theory

solve for x in :

a) $4x+3\equiv 8$ (mod9)

So do we just subtract the 3? I know how to solve if it were asking 
$4x\equiv 3$ (mod9) but Im not sure how to do the problem above.

Comment: Yes, subtract 3 from both sides, giving $4x\equiv 5\mod{9}$; then all you have to do is find the inverse of $4\mod 9$.

Comment: $4x\equiv 5\pmod9\Rightarrow x=8$ (because $4\cdot8=32=27+5$)

Answer (score 1):

it is $$4x\equiv 5\mod 9$$ so $$x\equiv \frac {5}{4}\mod 9$$ and we get
$$x\equiv \frac{5+9+9+9}{4}\equiv \frac{32}{4}\equiv 8\mod 9$$

Comment: What are fractions of integers modulo $9$?

Comment: add the $9$s *before* dividing by $4$, and this answer would be better

Comment: why would this be better?

Comment: Respectfully, I tend to side with Zubin on this one, but $4$ is coprime to $9$ so what you did is legitimate ...

Answer (score 1):

To solve $\;4x\equiv 5\mod 9$, you have to find the inverse of $4$ modulo $9$, which exists since $49-$ and $9$ are coprime;

Start from a *Bézout's relation* between $4$   and $9$:
$$1\cdot 9-2\cdot 4=1$$
This relation implies $\;(-2)4\equiv 1\mod 9$, so the inverse if $4$ modulo $9$ is $-2$ and we obtain the solution of the equation as follows:
$$x\equiv 5\mod 9 \implies (-2)4x\equiv (-2)5\mod 9\iff x\equiv-10\equiv-1\mod 9$$

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the 3

$4x \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$

In modulo, dividing is multiplying by the inverse, so we need to know what $4^{-1} \pmod{9}$ is. You can solve this using The extended euclidean algorithm, or with small modulos like this, just guess and check. We are looking for what to multiply 4 by to get one more than a multiple of 9 (because the inverse of a number is what we multiply the number with to obtain the identity, which in this case is 1), or

$4y \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$. Which ends up being $y = 7$ (since $7\cdot 4 = 28$ which is one more than 27, which is a multiple of 9), thus $4^{-1} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$

So now

$4^{-1}4x \equiv 4^{-1}5 \pmod{9} \Rightarrow x \equiv (7)5 \pmod{9} \Rightarrow x \equiv 35 \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$

Answer (score 1):

The reason we can subtract 3 on both sides is because
$4x +3 \equiv 11 (\mod 9) $ is the same as saying
$(4x+3)+9k=11$

$(4x+3)-3+9k=11-3 $

$(4x+3-3)+9k=8 \implies 4x \equiv 8 ( \mod 9)$